# Is it possible that a simple Akka Http request is so much different from a curl one?

Tags: scala, http, curl, akka-http

I'm trying to download data from the European Central Bank API. A simple curl works fine:
`curl "https://sdw-wsrest.ecb.europa.eu/service/data/EXR/D.USD.EUR.SP00.A?startPeriod=2018-06-06&endPeriod=2018-06-06"`

But when I try to achieve the same thing with Akka Http, all of a sudden I get a 500 error. Here is the code (you can run it in the browser and see it for yourself): https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ynqKN3ClQJmPUruybgR37g. Because the URLs are exactly the same, it means that the requests themselves must be different. How is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to add an Accept header to your request. This seems to work:

```
val httpRequest = HttpRequest(
  method = HttpMethods.GET,
  headers = List(Accept()),
  uri = uri)
val futureResponse = Http().singleRequest(httpRequest)
```

It appears that the service you are calling requires the Accept header and curl adds an `Accept: */*` header by default.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know what headers are added or not by default